# limitar días a elegir de un segundo input

Tags: javascript, php

tengo una duda, no se si es posible hacerlo, la idea es que cuando el usuario seleccione del primer input tipo `date` una fecha, el segundo input se habilite pero que este limitado a seleccionar 7 días desde la fecha elegida del primer input

```
  <label class="rep_text">Fecha: </label>
  <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha_diaP" placeholder="Fecha inicio" required class="form-control  mr-sm-2" min = '2024-03-11'><br/>
   <label class="rep_text">Hasta </label>
   <input type="date" name="fecha_diaP_1" class="form-control  mr-sm-2" min = '2024-03-11'>
```

No se mucho de JS actualmente estoy buscando, pero no encuentro nada relacionado. Si me podrian guiar de como arrancar o si es que no se puede. Agradecere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías comenzar con algo así:

```js
fecha1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (fecha1.checkValidity()) {
        fecha2.min = fecha1.value
        let fechafin = new Date(fecha1.value);
        fechafin.setDate(fechafin.getDate()+7);
        fecha2.max = fechafin.toISOString().split('T')[0];
        fecha2.disabled = false;
        if (!fecha2.checkValidity()) fecha2.value = "";
    } else {
        fecha2.disabled = true;
        fecha2.value = "";
        fecha2.min = "";
        fecha2.max = "";
    }
});
```

```html
<label class="rep_text">Fecha: </label>
<input type="date" id="fecha1" name="fecha_diaP" placeholder="Fecha inicio" required class="form-control mr-sm-2" min="2024-03-11"><br/>
<label class="rep_text">Hasta: </label>
<input type="date" id="fecha2" name="fecha_diaP_1" disabled class="form-control  mr-sm-2">
```

Comment: wow, justo lo que queria hacer.. increible.. muy amable